# Does ompl generate path or trajectory?

Tags: ros, ompl, joint-trajectory-action, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does ompl generate path or trajectory? If it generate trajectory, where it creates time, velocity and acceleration profile for a path?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65286/does-ompl-generate-path-or-trajectory?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the planner you use. Some planners might return paths, others trajectories. In my experience, all OMPL planners I've used so far return paths, and they get time-parameterized during a filtering step that follows planning. Filtering takes place outside OMPL but within the scope of arm_navigation / MoveIt!.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-17**:
Did you use RRTconnect planner before? I am interested using that. Does that generate path or trajectory?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-17**:
And do you know where filtering take place in moveit? in http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Groovy/API_Overview_Diagram, I found trajectory_processing. Is it used to time-parameterize path generated by ompl planners?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-06-17**:
RRTconnect and its variants output paths. Regarding the filtering step, MoveIt's Trajectory Processing functionalities implement the time parameterizations you're looking for. Note that there might be bundles of functionality that already do this for you, check the move_group action for example.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-17**:
I want to know how moveit implement time parameterization for path. I want to change the time parameterization to test the trajectory controllers. Thx for your help! I will look into Trajectory Processing.